# How to display best seller products category wise?

Tags: magento-1.9, conditional-loading

I'm using MageBees bestseller products extension. And want to customize it in order to get best selling products category wise.

Like **For Category A**,

Best Seller Products

**For Category B**,

Best Seller Products.

**For Category C**,

Best Seller Products.
And like wise.

What condition I should apply to get category wise bestseller products?

Answer (score 1):

You have to join data of table `catalog_category_product` with your bestseller product collection with `product_id` of category table and `product_id`  of your collection, and after that you can filer your collection by category id. Like this--

`$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')`

> Replace this collection with your collection and join with

```
->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => 'cat_id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following things

```
$productCollection = $objectManager1->create('Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\Factory');
        $bestSellerProdcutCollection = $productCollection->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection')->setPeriod('year');
        $bestSellerProdcutCollection->load();
        $bestSellerProdcutCollection->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE);
        $bestSellerProdcutCollection->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::GROUP);
        $bestSellerProdcutCollection->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER);
        if (!empty($category_url)) {
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
            $category = $categoryFactory->create()->loadByAttribute('url_key', $category_url);

            $category_id[] = $category->getId();
            $subcategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
            if (isset($subcategories) && !empty($subcategories)) {
                foreach ($subcategories as $subcategorie) {
                    $category_id[] = $subcategorie->getId();
                    $subcategorie1 = $subcategorie->getChildrenCategories();
                    foreach ($subcategorie1 as $subcat) {
                        $category_id[] = $subcat->getId();
                    }
                }
            }





            $bestSellerProdcutCollection->join(
                ['secondTable' =>'catalog_category_product'],
                "sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly.product_id=secondTable.product_id",
                []
            )->addFieldToFilter('category_id', ['in' => $category_id]);



        }

        $bestSellerProdcutCollection->join(
            ['thirdTable' =>'catalog_product_entity_int'],
            'sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly.product_id=thirdTable.entity_id',
            []
        )->addFieldToFilter('thirdTable.attribute_id', ['eq' => 97])
            ->addFieldToFilter('thirdTable.value', ['eq' => 1])
            ->addFieldToFilter('sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly.product_id', ['notnull' => true])
            ->addFieldToFilter('sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly.product_price', array('gt' => 0.0000));

        $bestSellerProdcutCollection->getSelect()->group('sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly.product_id')->order('sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly.qty_ordered DESC');
        $bestSellerProdcutCollection->setPageSize(10);
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager',
            'weismann.bestseller.pager'
        )->setAvailableLimit(array(10=>10))
            ->setShowPerPage(false)->setCollection(
                $bestSellerProdcutCollection
            );
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
```

In above example I had fetch data from main category url and get its all sub categories and then it get all best seller according to sub category.